# Is there a way to use build string and build number at the same time while building Conda Packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have multiple versions of a conda package which all install the same version of a library but have some additional dependencies listed. So I have to use the same version number and was using build number to tell conda which package is the latest. But now I want to add some additional info in the package name so I decided to use build string for that. But build string overrides the build number and the package name only contains the build string. Is there any way to use them both simultaneously? Separated by an underscore, the way conda does it implicitly for the "py36_" build string? package-1.0.0-"build_string"_1

for ex : for the meta.yaml below, is there a way to get the output tar file to be named as

tensorflow-1.8.0-py36_Cuda_compatible_1.tar.gz2

```
package:
  name: tensorflow
  version: "1.8.0"

build:
  number: 1
  string: "py36_Cuda_compatible"

requirements:
  build:
    - python=3.6
  run:
    - python
    - absl-py >=0.1.6
    - astor >=0.6.0
    - gast >=0.2.0
    - numpy >=1.13.3
    - six >=1.10.0
    - protobuf >=3.4.0
    - tensorboard >=1.8.0, <1.9.0
    - termcolor >=1.1.0
    - grpcio >=1.8.6

Test:

  imports:
    - tensorflow

about:
  home: http://tensorflow.org/
```

Comment: Can you please post your entire `meta.yaml`?

Comment: @darthbith I edited my post and added the meta.yaml file I am working with. Is such a naming scheme possible with using build string and build number?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

```
build:
  number: {{ any_env_var_also }}
  string: {{ PKG_BUILDNUM }}_{{ commit }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm essentially struggling with the same problem, where I'm trying to include commit hash into build number/string.

From what I can tell and this is just trying it out you can't use both. Which I think is a bit silly. I'd love to be able to do this:

```
{% set version = "0.0.1" %}                                                                                                                                                                                        
{% set commit = "fdafad8" %}                                                                                                                                                                                        

package:
  name: blah
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  git_rev: {{ version }}
  git_url: https://github.com/serine/blah

build:
  number: 0
  string: {{ commit }}
```

and get this

`blah-0.0.1-fdafad8_1.tar.gz2`

I can of course get that results by simply not having `number:` and having `string: fdafad8_1`, but like I said this is annoying.

The very annoying thing that I don't know how to solve and piggybacking on your question, is having the "right" version structure that sorts correctly when uploaded to Anaconda repository e.g

1. `blah-0.0.1-fdafad8_0.tar.gz2`
2. `blah-0.0.1-fdafad8_1.tar.gz2`

The behaviour that I expect when I `conda install -c serine blah` is I get the latest build - 1, but I'm getting build 0 :/

Have a look at this [article by Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/package-better-conda-build-3/) it might be useful to you, wasn't in my case.